# NFC module not discovered

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

So I am trying to make an app that sends an image to an NFC module connected to e-paper. I am currently stuck on trying to discover the module. For now I just want to make the detection of the NFC module work if that makes sense.
This is my code so far:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proba)

        performTagOperations(intent)
    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        this.nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        if(nfcAdapter == null) {
            Log.e("debug", "NFC is not supported!")
            return
        }
        if(!nfcAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            Log.e("debug", "NFC is not enabled!")
            return
        }

        if(nfcAdapter != null) {
            Log.e("debug", "NFC is ready!")
            try {
                val techLists = arrayOf(
                    arrayOf(IsoDep::class.java.name),
                    arrayOf(NfcV::class.java.name),
                    arrayOf(NfcF::class.java.name)
                )

                val filters = arrayOf(IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, "*/*"))

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 115, Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, techLists)
            }
            catch (e: MalformedMimeTypeException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("debug", "onResume-exception")
            }
        }
    }

private fun performTagOperations(intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        Log.e("debug", action.toString())
        if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC module detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e("debug", "Tag discovered")
        }
    }

override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        performTagOperations(intent)
    }
```

Every time the activity launches the intent.action is null. When I put the phone on the module after the activity is opened it doesn't enter onNewIntent. As far as I know I put in every permission needed and some more:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<activity
            android:name=".ProbaActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Also every time I put the phone on the module this screen opens:

[image: tag detected]

Also I have another app downloaded for uploading images to the module and it works just fine so it's not the phone's or the module's problem. Also I am new to NFC so it could be something trivial. I've been trying to find a fix for this for almost 2 days now and can't think of anything else. Thanks for your time!